# how to retrieve the particular label title from dynamically create label in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uilabel

I create the 10 labels dynamically in the view controller. When I click the particular label want to get the clicked label title how can i do this any on help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer to find when user click the label as follows:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [myLabel addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    [singleFingerTap release];
```

Then in handleSingleTap method you can find which label is tapped:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UILabel *view = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
    NSString *text = view.text;
}
```

Comment: @yuvaraj please mark the question as answered if this solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can sub class UILabel and in `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, you can returns its `text property value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tapgesturerecognizer. This will return the coords of of the tap.

You can then test if the coords of the tap were within the bounds of one of your dynamically created labels.

then you can fetch the title with the "text" property of the UILabel.